# Robolectric tests fail in terminal, succeed in Android Studio

Tags: android, robolectric

I've recently started to work on a new project, which includes Robolectric-based unit tests.

When ran from Android Studio (v3.6), all the tests pass successfully.
Strangely, some of the tests fail when I'm running them using `./gradlew test` from terminal with very intimidating error:

```
java.lang.VerifyError: Stack map does not match the one at exception handler 56
Exception Details:
  Location:
    com/google/android/gms/measurement/internal/zzjy.zza(Landroid/net/Uri;)Landroid/os/Bundle; @56: astore
  Reason:
    Type 'java/lang/String' (current frame, locals[5]) is not assignable to null (stack map, locals[5])
  Current Frame:
    bci: @51
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'com/google/android/gms/measurement/internal/zzjy', 'android/net/Uri', 'java/lang/String', 'java/lang/String', 'java/lang/String', 'java/lang/String' }
    stack: { 'java/lang/UnsupportedOperationException' }
  Stackmap Frame:
    bci: @56
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'com/google/android/gms/measurement/internal/zzjy', 'android/net/Uri', 'java/lang/String', 'java/lang/String', 'java/lang/String', null }
    stack: { 'java/lang/UnsupportedOperationException' }
  Bytecode:
    // redacted..    
  Exception Handler Table:
    bci [16, 53] => handler: 56
  Stackmap Table:
    same_frame(@6)
    full_frame(@53,{Object[#2],Object[#145],Object[#129],Object[#129],Object[#129],Object[#129]},{})
    full_frame(@56,{Object[#2],Object[#145],Object[#129],Object[#129],Object[#129],Null},{Object[#143]})
    full_frame(@74,{Object[#2],Object[#145],Object[#129],Object[#129],Object[#129],Object[#129]},{})
    same_frame(@104)
    append_frame(@128,Object[#172])
    same_frame(@143)
    same_frame(@160)
    same_frame(@177)
    append_frame(@201,Object[#129])
    append_frame(@225,Object[#129])
    append_frame(@249,Object[#129])
    append_frame(@273,Object[#129])
    append_frame(@297,Object[#129])
    full_frame(@300,{Object[#2],Object[#145],Object[#129],Object[#129],Object[#129],Object[#129]},{})
    at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzfl.<init>(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl@@17.1.0:42)
    at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzfl.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl@@17.1.0:285)
    at com.google.firebase.analytics.FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-api@@17.1.0:9)
    // redacted..
    at org.robolectric.android.internal.AndroidTestEnvironment.lambda$installAndCreateApplication$0(AndroidTestEnvironment.java:276)
    at org.robolectric.android.internal.AndroidTestEnvironment$$Lambda$45/1286999442.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.robolectric.util.PerfStatsCollector.measure(PerfStatsCollector.java:75)
    at org.robolectric.android.internal.AndroidTestEnvironment.installAndCreateApplication(AndroidTestEnvironment.java:276)
    at org.robolectric.android.internal.AndroidTestEnvironment.setUpApplicationState(AndroidTestEnvironment.java:169)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.beforeTest(RobolectricTestRunner.java:301)
    at org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner$2.lambda$evaluate$0(SandboxTestRunner.java:243)
    at org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner$2$$Lambda$28/968645498.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.Sandbox.lambda$runOnMainThread$0(Sandbox.java:89)
    at org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.Sandbox$$Lambda$29/1700079137.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Why the tests pass in Android Studio, but fail in terminal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why the tests pass in Android Studio, but fail in terminal?

It's because there's a JDK version mismatch between the one that's used when invoked from Android Studio versus the one that's used when invoked from the terminal.

---

**Which JDK version used by Gradle when invoked from the terminal?**

When ran from terminal, Gradle uses a version defined in `JAVA_HOME` - which on my machine pointed to (older version) 1.8.0-51.

**Which JDK version used by Gradle when invoked from Android Studio?**

[Starting from version 2.2](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config#jdk), a copy of the latest OpenJDK comes bundled with Android Studio.
In example, Android Studio 3.6 uses OpenJDK v1.8.0-212.

The JDK version you want Gradle to use when running your tasks from Android Studio can be found/set at `Project Structure` > `SDK Location` > `JDK Location`. By default, it is configured to use the bundled OpenJDK version.

**How did I solved the error?**

In order to reproduce the errors in Android Studio, I've changed the `JDK Location` to `JAVA_HOME`, ran the tests (from Android Studio) again, and voila! the errors I've seen only in terminal now appear in Android Studio as well.

To resolve the failures I've seen when ran the tests from terminal, I've updated the JDK pointed by `JAVA_HOME` to latest (1.8.0-251), and now tests pass both in Android Studio and when ran using `gradlew` from terminal.

Comment: Nice! It worked for me
Another way to point same java is adding this line to gradle.properties:

org.gradle.java.home=C\:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/jre